# How to detect netrw directory listing from autocommand?

Tags: autocmd, netrw

I want to detect from a `BufEnter` autocommand whether the buffer is a netrw directory listing.

It seems that when the autocommand is fired, the `filetype` is empty and there are no netrw-related buffer variables.  Furthermore the `bufname()` is empty.  However when I manually look at the `filetype` it is `"netrw"`, the `b:netrw_curdir` variable is set, and the buffer has a name (the directory it shows).

How can I determine during the autocommand when the buffer is a netrw directory listing?

This is on Vim 9.0.1276.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, netrw intercepts `BufEnter` itself to set the things up. So upon *first* `BufEnter` it depends on which autocmd was registered first: yours or netrw's one. As you want to go after netrw you can move your code under `~/.vim/after/plugin` directory, for example.

However, I'd rather switched to `BufWinEnter` event, as it gets triggered less often than `BufEnter` (only after the buffer is shown in a window for the first time, and not after every buffer switching) and after the first `BufEnter` event anyway. In many cases it might be just what one needs.

Also, I would consider dropping netrw at all, as it is... well, what to say, I really dislike it.

Comment: Aha, it makes sense that netrw would intercept `BufEnter`.  I tried to work through netrw's code but I found it very unclear.  I haven't used it myself for many years.  I'm trying to fix [an issue with vim-rooter](https://github.com/airblade/vim-rooter/issues/134).

Comment: `BufWinEnter` could work for my use case, I think.  I'll try it.

Comment: `BufWinEnter` seems to fire before `BufEnter` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Matt's answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/43046/1643) I realised I couldn't detect a netrw directory listing in a `BufEnter` autocommand (unless the code is running from an `after` directory).

So I switched to using a `Filetype netrw` autocommand.

Comment: At which point you might as well use `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim` or equivalent on your system.

Comment: This is all for a plugin and for some reason I thought that plugins couldn't have `after/` directories.  But it turns out they can :)

Comment: For a plugin, you probably don’t need after. I recommend it for personal configuration because 99% of the time it’s the right thing and it’s less confusing.